# What does "Milton" mean in this case?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In the movie "The Night at the Museum, " the protagonist Larry says "I'm Larry, son of Milton," after the pharaoh introduces himself as "the Fourth King of the Fourth King, Ruler of the Land of my Fathers."

Does Larry mean that his father's name is Milton?

And this is off topic, but is it common for kings to introduce themselves by repeating phrases(Fourth King of the Fourth King)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, "Milton" is 99% likely to be his Father, 1% likely to be his Mother.

I'm not sure that any modern King would introduce himself quite like you suggest, (not least because they generally get someone else to introduce them!), but it is pretty common in literature / movies.

Comment: We don't normally capitalise relationship names, such as mother, father, sister, brother, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, his father's name is Milton.

The Pharaoh's words are meant to suggest the way that kings are referred to in ancient inscriptions (like [this Persian one](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Sculptures_and_Inscription_of_Darius_the_Great_on_the_Rock_of_Behist%C3%BBn_in_Persia/Annotated/The_Persian_Text) - I didn't find an Egyptian one).

The Joke is that Larry feels the need to reply in the same way, but the best he can come up with is the name of his father, who is completely undistinguished.